# How to reset UIPanGestureRecognizer? Calling "reset" generates "Value of type 'UIPanGestureRecognizer' has no member 'reset'" error

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

The docs for [UIGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620004-reset) reference a `reset` function.

However, calling `reset()` on a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, which is a child of `UIGestureRecognizer`, generates this error message:

> Value of type 'UIPanGestureRecognizer' has no member 'reset'

How do you reset a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` during the "changed" state?

Answer (score 1):

If the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is called `recognizer`, here's how you can reset it:

```
recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: recognizer.view!)
```

Answer (score 0):

try import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass